# Notepad++ search for 2 consecutive words that is separated by white space(s), tab or newline, and has white space(s), tab or newline immediately

Tags: notepad++, regex

I rarely use regular expressions, but I have a task at work that needs to be done quickly.

I'm using notepad++ to search through a directory containing a lot of sql scripts.

I need to search for  2 consecutive words that are separated by white space(s), tab or newline, and has white space(s), tab or newline immediately before and after it:

1)

> set mgtfee  [ Should Match ]

2)

> set
>   mgtfee [ Should Match ]

I tried the following but it did Not work

```
(\w|^)set\mgtfee(\w|$)
```

Comment: Please edit and give some proper examples of text that should match and text that shouldn't. I suspect your current specification is too broad and is going to give you a lot of false positives as it will match any two consecutive words anywhere in any file.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

- Find what: `\s*set\s+mgtfee\s*`

Comment: I believe that this is wrong.  Remember that `*` matches ***zero** or more* characters, so this would match "setmgtfee".

Comment: @Scott: You're right, fixed.